# Magento data migration M 1.9.2.4 to M2.4.2 show integrity error & missing data in admin panel for product

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration, data-migration-tool, missing

I have am doing data migration via taking backup of production site db on local and installing new fresh M2.4.2 magento.

Setting migration done successfully.
Setting migration command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:setting "app/code/Custom/Migration/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml" --reset
```

While doing data migration I have got below error but even this error the migration show completed.

Command I run for data migration:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data -a "app/code/Custom/Migration/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml" --reset
```

[image]

After this I run all magento command and do some changes in db for theme related entry issue and again run magento commands then login to admin.

When I open product I have found some of the product information is missing not showing in admin even if present in database, Like manufacturer, category and some of custom product attribute values not showing but the entries are present in database.

Also product qty, weight, price and product stock status is lso not up to the mark.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue and the issue is resolved after these steps:
[image]

[image]

And then Clean cache and open catalog->default category and enable that and save again